# Making a Username and Password with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, passwords

I've seen other questions similar to this, but I've tried answers and it doesn't appear to do what I want (if it does and I just can't see that it does, please just let me know in the comments. I'm pretty new to this).

I want to password protect a website (this is a personal family website, so I'm not worried about encryption or anything, unless it's super easy to do with javascript) so that only my family can get on. I want the passwords to be personalized.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form id="usr-psswd">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usr" id="usr">
  Password: <input type="text" name="psswd" id="psswd">
  <input type="button" onclick="submission()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Script Code**

```
function submission(){
  var name = document.getElementByID = "name";
  var psswd = document.getElementByID = "psswd";
  var usr = document.getElementByID = "usr";

  var name = new Array();
  var usr = new Array();
  var psswd = new Array();
}
```

**My Question:** how do I get javascript to put the input into an array that stays on the page so that when you try to get to index.html (which is where the password protection is) so that they don't have to set this up every time?

Also, if it's simple enough, how can I run multiple passwords through encryption and keep it on the webpage so that if someone happens to get on here the passwords are safe?

Yes, I realize that the `var name` `var psswd` and `var usr` are repeated twice. That's because I'm too lazy to name them different things right now. I just need to know how to put `var name = document...` into `var name = new...`. Thanks!

Comment: The passwords will never be safe, nor will the page, because every client that has access to the page will also have open access to both the encrypted password and the method you use to encrypt them. Plus anybody can easily completely bypass the authentication by just typing JavaScript commands in the browser's console. This is why authentication is done server side. At minimum see if you can just configure run of the mill http basic authentication on the web server, over HTTPS, which is better than nothing at least.

Comment: The only way to remember something client-side is by using global variables. But this is certainly not what you want to save a password in there. You should save this kind of stuff in a php SESSION or something. Your submission() function is wrong too by the way. To get form contents, you say: document.getElementById("name"); And then later you overwrite it with an array?

Comment: @JasonC I don't have a server (at least not one that I know of) and my php is non existent. How would I save them server side? Also, the page is only being given to my family, so I'm not worried too much about information being stolen. I also have a disclaimer that it's not encrypted and to not reuse other passwords. Again with the bypass. There's no sensitive information being kept here, so that's not a concern.

Comment: @Saskia Thanks! I didn't know the correct syntax for the `document.getElementByID` As I pointed out, I have the two separate vars. I want the first `var name` to put information in the `var name` array (I'll rename these vars for the website. I'm just trying to clarify what goes where).

Comment: Why include password at all, if you aren't going to make it any safer? it's like putting a single strip of duct tape across your front door and not locking it with the rationale that only your friends and family will visit and the duct tape will make it _slightly_ harder for somebody to enter.

Comment: @James what you are proposing is more unsafe than having a website without authentication. People WILL reuse their password and those passwords are going to be REALLY easy to grab. Besides, people can disable JavaScript on their browsers and access the website anyways. I advice you to either do it without authentication or do server side authentication.

Comment: @James: The way you're proposing to do this make no sense, because anyone can retrieve the user/pass and access the site, so it renders it useless, you're also exposing the passwords to the world by doing so, so like Rodolfo said, if someone reuses the password they're screwed. Also, even if you share the URL only to your friends/family.. The site is still public, so it's accessible to anyone.

Comment: *"I don't have a server"* – How are people going to see the site then?

Comment: @deceze Like I said, I'm new. Does buying a domain count as a server? Or is a server something else?

Answer (score 3):

I know you said that you wanted to do a simple authentication for the site, but doing it in JavaScript is unsafe and the usernames/passwords are easily retrieved.

If you want something very simple and fast to do.. I suggest you do this by using `.htaccess` for authentication:

To do this, The system requires two files -- the `.htaccess` file and `.htpasswd` file:

**The .htaccess Code:**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /home/user/html/protect-me-dir/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

The above code protects a directory called `protect-me-dir` at root level. The `AuthUserFile` value is always specific to your hosting configuration. If you don't know what the value should be, do a phpinfo() and find the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

---

**The .htpasswd Code:**

```
your_username:your_password
another_user:another_password
you_get:the_idea
```

The .htpasswd file contains the usernames and passwords of allowed users. One per line.

---

Otherwise, I'd probably do something fancier by maybe having a proper login using a combination of PHP and a database for example.

I hope this helps.

Comment: 1. MD5 is _hashing_ not _encrypting_. Encryptions are reversible, hashes aren't. 2. MD5 is _not_ secure. Other than that, though, the basic authentication is probably the simplest thing you can have which is also useful. It's not pretty (it's, after all, basic) but it will protect from most unauthorised access attempts which the JS "security" will happily let through.

Comment: Right, You are correct about MD5, I'll revise that part... Also the reason why I mentioned the `.htaccess` is because to me it seems like he's looking for basic auth. :D

Comment: I agree - basic authentication does seem like what OP wants.

Comment: It is what I'm looking for but I know nothing about php. Is there a step by step tutorial on this, or could you make me one? I'll ask a different question if I have to.

Comment: @James Using .htaccess and .htpasswd has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: My answer has literally everything you need to do in order to achieve basic authentication.. Just create two files and follow the instructions above.. :D

Comment: @Fadi the files are named ".htaccess" and ".htpasswd" and the code you supplied is all I need? And how do I reference these files and do I upload them to the domain or do I leave them on my laptop? Like I said, I know nothing.

Comment: Where's the site hosted? Like, do you have access to the site's FTP? Can you upload files to the site?